# Как связаны интонация текста и партитура стихотворения?

Tags: общие-вопросы, интонация

На уроках русского языка изучают фонетику,  а следовательно,  и интонацию как часть фонетической системы **русского языка,** например:
Основные элементы интонации. Функции интонации. Мультимедийный урок по русскому языку в 10-м классе по теме "Интонация".

**Почему интонация важна именно для русского языка?**
Интонация обозначает структуру предложения, определяет смысловые отношения между ее частями, а на письме ту же функцию выполняют знаки препинания. Мелодика речи и паузы – это основные элементы интонации, с ними важно познакомиться на уроках русского языка.

"Высота голоса (мелодика речи) – это движение голоса вверх и вниз, его повышение или понижение.  Мелодике речи принадлежит едва ли не основная роль. **В сочетании с логическим ударением и паузами мелодика фонетически оформляет смысловые отношения между частями фразы и объединяет их в выражении связной мысли или последовательности мыслей".**
[Элементы интонации | studopedia.su](http://studopedia.su/3_9650_elementi-intonatsii.html)

**И вопросы по партитуре:**
Можно ли написать партитуру стихотворения (ее изучают на уроках литературы) без знания основ интонации (ее изучают на уроках русского языка)?
Могут ли  вопросы по партитуре обсуждаться на форуме?

Comment: *Почему интонация важна именно для русского языка?* Странный вопрос. Разве для других языков интонация не важна? Например, для английского, грузинского.

Comment: Артем, я могу объяснить роль интонации только в русском языке.  Каждое предложение  - это набор фраз, например, простое предложение состоит из двух фраз: восходящего тона и нисходящего тона.  Появление однородных членов меняет структуру: теперь каждый член - это отдельная фраза. Каждая фраза имеет одно тоническое ударение - это ударение связывает между собой отдельные слова, как словесное ударение связывает слоги, чтобы получилось слово. Общее значение: повышение тона - это незаконченность сообщения или вопрос, понижение тона делается в конце предложения или его части. И т.д.

Comment: Да это понятно. Меня удивило, будто для русского языка интонация важна, а **для других — нет.**

Comment: Возможно, в других языках она менее важна. Чтобы судить об этом, надо знать  функцию интонации в каждом случае. Кстати, роль интонации в фонетической системе р.я. понятна далеко не всем. Изучают элементы интонации в высшей школе, а выразительно читать стихи учат уже в младших классах.  И кто составляет партитуры, школьники или студенты, тоже непонятно.

Answer (score 2):

Я прочитал комментарии к вопросу и удивился, не увидев там самого очевидного, на мой взгляд, ответа. Русский язык отличается от многих европейских языков значительной свободой расстановки слов внутри предложения. Обычно мы намеренно выбираем тот или иной порядок слов, вкладывая в это определённый смысл. **Но даже после выбора порядка слов у нас по-прежнему остаётся довольно много свободы в том, каким смыслом мы хотим наделить фразу, особенно в устной речи. Самых характерный пример, разумеется, заключается в том, что одинаковый порядок слов может соответствовать как утверждению, так и вопросу.** Но на этом часто всё не заканчивается; ставя ударение на том или ином слове, мы можем придавать предложению дополнительную окраску. Одним словом, интонационные возможности невероятно обогощают язык.